# Installing cf-console returns error

Tags: github, go

Im fairly new to Git stuff and I need to install the following and I wonder how to do that?

https://github.com/danhigham/cf-console

I've installed cloud foundry so in the CLI I can put CF commands and its working...
I've also installed Go and when I put the following in the command line

```
cf install-plugin $C:/Go/bin/cf-console
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing plugin $C:/Go/bin/cf-console...
FAILED
exec: "$C:/Go/bin/cf-console": file does not exist
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does `echo $C` give you back?  Also, are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @Makoto - Im using windows...I put the C:/ since in the installation its write $GOPATH/bin/cf-console ...this is wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `'$'` sign, just try `C:/Go/bin/cf-console`.

Comment: You shouldn't need the $; that is more specific and geared towards Unix-based systems and their terminal variables.  If you just use the path, you should be okay.

Comment: @icza-Thanks I did what you said and I got error File not found locally, make sure the file exists at given path ...any idea ?

Comment: @Makoto - I put the following cf install-plugin C:/Go/bin/cf-console
and I got error File not found locally, make sure the file exists at given path ...
what it can be ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Makoto-Do you think I should do pre requisite  step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows setup for Go `C:\Go` is where Go is installed.

Set GOPATH to another folder, and use `%GOPATH%\bin\cf-console`.
Make sure `go get github.com/danhigham/cf-console` works first:

- you should see %GOPATH%\src\github.com\danhigham\cf-console`
- you should be able to do a `go install` in that folder.
- that would generate the executable you need

On Windows, the actual command mentioned in the [`README`](https://github.com/danhigham/cf-console/blob/master/README.md) should be:

```
cf install-plugin %GOPATH%\bin\cf-console
```

Comment: Thanks but how should I use the  go get github.com/danhigham/cf-console,im new to go...

Comment: @Mark you just type it in your CMD shell session. But first, make sure your go setup is complete: https://golang.org/doc/install#windows: GOPATH should *not* be C:\Go. First check your Go setup, *then* try to get that package.

Comment: Thanks von voted up! I've install the MSI but im not sure what is setGOPATH to another folder ,do I need to use this command in windows cli?to which path? Thanks in advance~

Comment: I saw in the env varible that I've GOROOT value C:\Go\

Comment: Set `GOPATH` to the folder you want, like `C:\users\<mylogin>\go`: follow http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm. Then check the output of `go env`.

Comment: Thanks I did it and I was able to do the get and the install (I see now in folder C:\GoPath the bin&pkg&src folder of the console) but now I go to my application path (in cmd) and did cf console appName and I got error cf: 'console' is not a registered command. See 'cf help' ,any idea?  do I need do additional steps?

Comment: @Mark if the go installation is complete, does the `go get github.com/danhigham/cf-console` work? Do you see `%GOPATH%\src\github.com\danhigham\cf-console` (like in, for example, `C:\users\<mylogin>\go\src\github.com\danhigham\cf-console`)? Remember, any executable you are building will be in `%GOPATH%\bin`, not `C:\Go\bin`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82800/discussion-between-mark-and-vonc).

Comment: Yes Von I see it its installed currently I guess... in the new folder I see %GOPATH%\src\github.com\danhigham\cf-console , but what should I do now to make it work?